# Efficient use of YAML anchors in lists with nearly identical elements

Tags: yaml

I have this pattern in a YAML file:

```
  X:
    - B: 1
      C:
        c1: 1
        c2: 0
      D
        d1: 9
        d2: 27
    - B: 1
      C:
        c1: 2
        c2: 0 
      D
        d1: 9
        d2: 27
    - B: 1
      C:
        c1: 3
        c2: 0 
      D
        d1: 9
        d2: 27
```

In practice, for each element in the list there are many keys (beyond just `B`, `C`, and `D`).  The contents of each element in the list is nearly identical--only `c1` inside `C` changes.

Is there a way I can use anchors to avoid having to re-write each element in the list, defining say some template list element and subsequently modifying just `c1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your YAML implementation supports the [merge key](https://yaml.org/type/merge.html) (quite some do, but it is not required as it is a left-over from YAML 1.1), you can do

```yaml
  X:
    - &a
      B: 1
      C:
        c1: 1
        c2: 0
      D:
        d1: 9
        d2: 27
    - <<: *a
      C:
        c1: 2
        c2: 0 
    - <<: *a
      C:
        c1: 3
        c2: 0
```

This merges key-value pairs from the first sequence item into the other items, but skips `C` as it is overridden. You cannot skip `c1` since the merge key will not merge the content of the newly given `C`.

If the actual non-changing content of `C` is larger and you don't want to repeat it, you can additionally do

```yaml
  X:
    - &a
      B: 1
      C:
        <<: &b
          c2: 0
        c1: 1
      D:
        d1: 9
        d2: 27
    - <<: *a
      C:
        <<: *b
        c1: 2
    - <<: *a
      C:
        <<: *b
        c1: 3
```

This is the only templating facility YAML supports. To do more complex templating, you will need a templating engine on top of YAML. Many heavy YAML users, like e.g. Ansible, SaltStack and others, use one to do such things. It depends on your environment whether you have a templating engine available.

Comment: This works.  Are you saying that without a templating facility, I need to explicitly write out all of ```C``` for each list entry even though I will only ever need to change ```c1``` under ```C```?

Comment: @rhz I edited in a way to avoid repeating non-changing `C` content, but that is the best you can get with YAML alone.

Comment: makes perfect sense.